# Ninject: Ignore Inject when not binded anything

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I want that Ninject does not throw Exception when there is an [Inject] attribute but that type was not binded before into ninject. Just ignore it or put null on it. 
I tried this code on creation of kernel but didn't help:

```
kernel.Components.RemoveAll<IMissingBindingResolver>();
kernel.Components.Add<IMissingBindingResolver, DefaultValueBindingResolver>();
```

But when running throws `Ninject.ActivationException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decorate it also with `[Optional]` attribute.

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Attributes/OptionalAttribute.cs